# "Inverting back" the inverted supply equation in an ECM. Possible?

Tags: time-series, econometrics, elasticity, ecm, economics

I am estimating a time series 2SLS, ECM model, for electricity consumption. The system has a demand equation:

[image: Formula]

The price is endogenous in the demand equation, and therefore, I also estimate a price equation using instruments:

[image: Formula]
[image: Formula]

A paper I have been reading makes an interesting point about this setup. The price function is essentially an inverted supply function. That begs the question: can I get from the price equation to the supply equation by a simple rewrite of equation 2? Simply put, just by switching sides for price and quantity?

Anyway, I'm estimating the **long run relationship** (elasticity) between demand and price, which for this setup is given by the fraction:

[image: Formula]

In the price equation, the elasticity of price with respect to demand is:

[image: Formula]

It's not the purpose of the model, but I can find that the estimated elasticity of price with respect to demand (quantity) is 0.109. I.e., price increases 0.1% for a 1% increase in quantity.

Is it possible (and valid) to turn this around to express it as the elasticity of supply wrt. price? Essentially doing something like:

[image: Formula]